# unable to install compass

Tags: ruby, cygwin, ffi, compass

Last week I made an update in cygwin because of the bash "vulnerable problem". 
After that I couldn't compile sass anymore. 
I tried to reinstall ruby, after some install fails and reinstalling cygwin I installed it and updated with 
"gem update --system" 
it run, but when I tried to install compass I got following message:

```
> /usr/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20141006-7856-1td7wzb.rb extconf.rb 
> checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***  Could not create
> Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary  libraries
> and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may 
> need configuration options.
> 
> Provided configuration options: 
> --with-opt-dir 
> --without-opt-dir 
> --with-opt-include 
> --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include 
> --with-opt-lib 
> --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib 
> --with-make-prog 
> --without-make-prog 
> --srcdir=. 
> --curdir 
> --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby 
> --with-ffi_c-dir 
> --without-ffi_c-dir 
> --with-ffi_c-include 
> --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include 
> --with-ffi_c-lib 
> --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/ 
> --with-libffi-config 
> --without-libffi-config 
> --with-pkg-config 
> --without-pkg-config  /usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError) 
> You have to install development tools first.  from
> /usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:565:in `try_cpp'  from
> /usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1044:in `block in have_header'  from
> /usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:895:in `block in checking_for'  from
> /usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block (2 levels) in postpone' 
> from /usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'  from
> /usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block in postpone'  from
> /usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'  from
> /usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in `postpone'  from
> /usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:894:in `checking_for'  from
> /usr/share/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1043:in `have_header'  from
> extconf.rb:16:in `<main>'
> 
> extconf failed, exit code 1
```

I tried to install ffi ("gem install ffi" and "gem install ffi --pre"),I got the same message

here is the log (.gem/ruby/extensions/x86_64-cygwin/ffi-1.9.5/gem_make.out)

```
package configuration for libffi is not found 
"gcc -o conftest.exe -I/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0 -I. -ggdb -O2 -pipe -Wimplicit-function-declaration conftest.c -L. -L/usr/lib -L. -fstack-protector -lruby200 -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt " 
checked program was: 
/* begin */ 
1: #include "ruby.h" 
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv) 
4: { 
5: return 0; 
6: } 
/* end */
```

I'm really frustrated!!'

system Windows 7 64bit 
Cygwin

Comment: I know it's been a while, but have you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 30):

Yep, for me it's just the `gcc` environment,so you can try

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

That worked for me in ubuntu :)

Comment: For CentOS, `yum install gcc`

Comment: I had to install make in addition to gcc using `sudo apt-get install make`

Comment: Read the question. Kornking's OS is Windows.

Answer (score 4):

make sure that xcode is installed.

```
xcode-select --install
```

if it is already installed, make sure that you have accepted the TOS.

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```

scroll down to the bottom and type agree.

it should work with above steps.

if you see following issue after doing above 2 steps

```
ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/compass
```

try following.

```
sudo su
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin compass
```

Comment: If you'd actually read the question, you would have noticed that Kornking's system is WIndows. So... no XCode.

Answer (score 3):

On OSX this worked:

if `gem install compass` fails, try

`gem install ffi`
in case that also fails, the error seems to be, that the ffi build looks in `/usr/bin` for `gcc-4.2`

if you have gcc installed, just create a symlink within `/usr/bin` by typing

`sudo ln -s gcc gcc-4.2`

otherwise you may need to first install gcc (google that)

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

download and install ruby dev kit as per your ruby version

http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

in case of any issue follow this wiki on github.

https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

Answer (score 0):

This is very old thread, but as I struggled a long time trying to work around that same issue I thought it could be helpful for someone else...

What worked in the end for me : uninstall ruby 3.1.x and reinstall it using the rubyinstaller-devkit-2.7.5-1-x64.exe available here : https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

Make sure to install the devTools at the end