# Errors installing ffi-1.9.10 gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ffi

I've manually installed (download and install locally):
Selenium Standalone Server 3.40
IE Driver Server 3.4 (32 bit)
childprocess 0.7.1

When I try to install ffi 1.9.10 manually I get the following gem_make.out error.  Internet security is pretty tight so I am unable to gem install filename.gem.  I have to do the local install.  Thanks

```
current directory: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/ffi-
1.9.10/ext/ffi_c
C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170731-1340-doe9ur.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You 
may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-ffi_c-dir
    --without-ffi_c-dir
--with-ffi_c-include
--without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
--with-ffi_c-lib
--without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
--with-libffi-config
--without-libffi-config
--with-pkg-config
--without-pkg-config
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:457:in `try_do': The compiler failed to 
generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:588:in `try_cpp'
from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:1095:in `block in have_header'
from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:945:in `block in checking_for'
from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in 
postpone'
from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:944:in `checking_for'
from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/2.4.0/mkmf.rb:1094:in `have_header'
from extconf.rb:16:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which 
can be found here:

 C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0/ffi-
1.9.10/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Here's my mkmf.log file

```
package configuration for libffi is not found
"x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-
2.4.0/x64-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/backward -
IC:/Ruby24-x64/include/ruby-2.4.0 -I. -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -
D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -IC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libffi-
3.2.1/include -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -
D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -I 
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby24-
x64/lib -L. -pipe     -lx64-msvcrt-ruby240  -lgmp -lshell32 -lws2_32 -
liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */
```

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: Have you seen this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26214435/unable-to-install-compass. It's about another gem, but with the same error (`package configuration for libffi is not found`).

Comment: I stepped through the resolution you mentioned above but I continued to having the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

This was not the easiest solution by any means, but begging to the network team I was able to get the permissions to download and install the gems the easy way "gem install selenium-webdriver".